# Generate jar files from required project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a Java project composed by many jar files, let's say the application directory is composed by the following jar files:

- File_1.jar
- File_2.jar
- ...
- File_N.jar

In addition there is a file executable file which makes use of the jar files

For some reason I am responsible of modifying two jar files, les's say File_1.jar and File_2.jar with the particularity that File_2.jar requieres the project associated to File_1.jar in the build path.

I generated the jar files without problems, so rigth now the application has the following jar files:

- File_1_modif.jar
- File_2_modif.jar
- File_1.jar
- File_2.jar
- ...
- File_N.jar

Everything went fine, I mean I could execute the application with my modifications but my problem came up when I removed the old jar files(File_1.jar, File_2.jar) from the application directory. Actually I do not get an error message but the application does not behave as it did before removing the old jar files, I was wondering if I should generate the file File_1_modif.jar in an special way due to the fact that this file is requiered to build the file File_2_modif.jar. Could anybody advice my some tries to do in order to fix my problem?

Comment: I don't think you need File_1.jar and File_2.jar if you have their content along with the modified content in the new jars respectively.

Comment: I think the same, that is the reason why I removed File_1.jar and File_2.jar but then I the got the behavieur I described in the post

Comment: Check your modified jar content, compare with original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your project is still referencing the File_1.jar and File_2.jar. You may need to locate how the jar files are being loaded into your project, if in eclipse or netbeans, you'll need to add the File_1_modif and file_2_modif files to your build path and remove the file_1.jar and file_2.jar. If you are using ant build, you will have to include the .jar files using directives like this:

```
                <fileset dir="${lib}">
                    <include name="file_1_modif.jar"/>
                    <include name="file_1_modif.jar"/>
                    <exclude name="**/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
                </fileset>
```

Comment: Since I am not using ant, I removed all the references to the old jar in the buid path, is it enough? or there is some other action I should do?

Comment: yes, that should be enough except the jar files are referencing other libraries you are not referencing in the new modified file. The easiest way to troubleshoot this will be to rename file_1.jar to file_1_modif.jar and try using that. if it works, then the problem is with the new jar files.

Comment: Confirmed! The problem is in the new jar files. I an going to compare the old jar files with the new files as suggested RC.

Comment: Finally and after understanding that I was missing a configuration file requiered by [SPI](http://code.google.com/p/spi/) I managed to succeed. Thanks all of you! My vote goes to @stdapsy for his hints.